# fetching items from array and putting it on a loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to fetch items from an array. So here's what my list look like.

Here's what my items look like

```
fruits[apple] = 'apple';
fruits[grapes] = 'grapes';
fruits[banana] = 'banana';

animals[dog] = 'dog';
animals[cat] = 'cat';
....
```

and my loop should look something like this.

```
<ul>
   <li> <a href="fruits/<?php echo $fruits ?>"><?php echo $fruits ?></a> </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(is_array($fruits) && count($fruits) > 0){
    echo "<ul>\n";
    foreach($fruits as $fruit){
        echo "<li><a href=\"fruits/".$fruit."\">".$fruit."</a></li>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
} else {
    echo "No Fruits :(";
}
```

Simples!

You can do the same with animals too...

Comment: Added in simple check to see if something is there, otherwise an error pops out

Comment: This works for me! thanks... prodigitalson is also a good approach.

Answer (score 2):

MrJ already gave you the answer but im posting this so you can see alternative and IMO better, cleaner syntax:

```
<?php if(count($fruits)): // dont output unless we actually have fruits! ?>
  <ul>
  <?php foreach($fruits as $fruit): ?>
     <li><a href="fruits/<?php echo $fruit ?>"><?php echo $fruit ?></a></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Even better is to use `printf` to create the link so we dont have to keep switching in and out of php while still avoiding crazy string concatenation to produce html:

```
<?php if(count($fruits)): // dont output unless we actually have fruits! ?>
  <ul>
  <?php foreach($fruits as $fruit): ?>
     <li><?php printf('a href="%s">%s</a>', $fruit, $fruit) ?></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```